# Can't run GWT sample

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to run GWT sample `StockWatcher`. I user `webAppCreator` to get the progect for eclipse following all instructions in Google tutorial. Then I import my progect to Eclipse, set "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox in project properties an click Debug As -> Web Application. Then I get

```
Started code server on port 9997
Parsing file:<some file path>/StockWatcher/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
   startElement: web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   startElement:   servlet
   startElement:     servlet-name
     characters:       greetServlet
     endElement:     servlet-name
   startElement:     servlet-class
     characters:       com.company.gwt.stockwatcher.server.GreetingServiceImpl
     endElement:     servlet-class
     endElement:   servlet
   startElement:   servlet-mapping
   startElement:     servlet-name
     characters:       greetServlet
     endElement:     servlet-name
   startElement:     url-pattern
     characters:       /stockwatcher/greet
     endElement:     url-pattern
     endElement:   servlet-mapping
   startElement:   welcome-file-list
   startElement:     welcome-file
     characters:       StockWatcher.html
     endElement:     welcome-file
     endElement:   welcome-file-list
     endElement: web-app
Loading modules
   \-remoteUI
      [ERROR] Invalid module name: '\-remoteUI'
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
   Parsing response (length 1443)
   Ping delay is 1; next ping at Tue Apr 17 13:06:08 EEST 2012
   Server version (2.3.0) is not newer than 2.4.0
```

Here is my **web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.company.gwt.stockwatcher.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/stockwatcher/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>StockWatcher.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Here is **StockWatcher.gwt.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='stockwatcher'>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

  <entry-point class='com.company.gwt.stockwatcher.client.StockWatcher'/>

  <source path='client'/>
  <source path='shared'/>

</module>
```

The problem repeats even if I download the project from tutorials page. How can I resolve the problem?

UPD: Strange, but when I tried to launch it again (no changes) I got "Problem occured" window:

> 'Launching StockWatcher' has encountered a problem.
>
> Variable references empty selection: ${container_path}

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the problem by deleting debug configuration. When I tried to run in debug mode Eclipse has generated new debug configuration and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check what are the available modules in GWT tab in Run Configurations window by right clicking on project and selecting Run menu item.

Comment: There are two modules: StockWatcher and StockWatcherJUnit. I tried to remove StockWatcherJUnit, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your launch configuration depends on the project location.So, before you run your launch configuration you need to have your project selected in the project explorer so that Eclipse can know which project’s location you want to refer to.